# Doctrine error in mapping many namespaces inside Zend Framework 2 module structure

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I'm getting an error from Doctrine2 while it tries to map my class structure.

My Zend Application's modules is structured as follows:

```
module
    ModuleOne
        config
            module_config.php
        src
            ModuleOne
                Entity
                    ClassOne.php
            ModuleOneAdmin
                Entity
                    ClassTwo.php
                    ClassTwoRepository.php
        Module.php
    ModuleTwo
        config
            module_config.php
        src
            ModuleTwo
                Entity
                    ClassThree.php
        Module.php
```

I've two subnamespaces inside ModuleOne, so, my autoloader (in ModuleOne/Module.php) is configured this way:

```
public function getAutoloaderConfig()
{
    return array(
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'namespaces' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ . 'Admin' => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . 'Admin',
                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__
            ),
        ),
    );
}
```

In ModuleOne/config/module_config.php, the doctrine is configured

```
'doctrine' => array(
    'driver' => array(
        __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => array(
            'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
            'cache' => 'array',
            'paths' => array(
                __DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Entity'
            )
        ),
        'orm_default' => array(
            'drivers' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'
            ),
        ),
    ),
)
```

I'm using the ModuleOne and ModuleTwo in another module (that I didn't specified in modules structure to avoid making it exhaustive) that possesses Controllers and Views.

When I run my application, it gets and error in a line that calls for a repository of the an Entity:

```
$repository = $this->getEm()->getRepository('ModuleOneAdmin\Entity\ClassTwo');
```

The error is:

```
The class 'ModuleOneAdmin\Entity\ClassTwo' was not found in the chain configured namespaces ModuleOne\Entity, ModuleTwo\Entity
```

I've searched a lot of other questions about something like this here in StackOverflow and in others sites from a google search, but none addressed my issue. Its like the Doctrine can't find my ModuleOneAdmin in its internal mappings. Is there some configuration that I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem, I didn't included the path to the drivers of the admin entities folder, in the doctrine configurations.

With the code below it works.

```
'doctrine' => array(
    'driver' => array(
        __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => array(
            'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
            'cache' => 'array',
            'paths' => array(
                __DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Entity'
            )
        ),
        'orm_default' => array(
            'drivers' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver',
                __NAMESPACE__ . 'Admin\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'
            ),
        ),
    ),
)
```